# ReactJS: how can I access parent element width from child component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components

FIXED: I missed to add .current to my ref...

I need to know the width of the element that will contain my component: looking at SO I found a solution but it didn't work for me (it returns undefined):

```
import React from 'react';

import './Badger.css';

export default function Badger(props) {

  const refContainer = React.useRef(null);

  React.useLayoutEffect(()=>{
    // console.log(refContainer); I missed .current, now it works
    console.log(refContainer.current); // Change the line to this
  });

  const items = props.items ? props.items : [];

  return <div ref={refContainer}>{ items.join(", ") }</div>

}
```

The parent element in this case is a td:

```
<td>
  <Badger
    items={r.to}
    listContainerWidth={recipientsWidth}
  />
</td>
```

But it console.log returns "undefined". How can I get the parent element?

Comment: If you fixed the problem, you're welcome to post it as an answer and mark your own solution as accepted (rather than as an edit to the original post).

Answer (score 0):

I missed .current in my ref. If you edit the code as follows it will fix the issue!

```
React.useLayoutEffect(()=>{
  // console.log(refContainer); I missed .current, now it works
  console.log(refContainer.current); // Change the line to this
});
```